# Why is the solution to this sum of two sines so complex?

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

While working on a signal processing problem, I found I needed to solve a certain equation involving a sum of a sequence of sines. Since I wasn't really sure how to do this cleanly, I decided to ask WolframAlpha to solve a simplified version (the first two terms) and see if there was a general pattern I could extrapolate.

To my utter surprise, the equation

$$ \sin(a-x) + 2\sin(b-2x) = 0$$

produced [this monstrosity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0+%3D+%5Csin(a-x)+%2B+2%5Csin(b-2x)) (note that this is just one of two solutions!):

> [image: WolframAlpha result]

What exactly is going on here? Why is the solution to this equation so absurdly complex?

I ended up solving my problem another way, but I still would love to know what is with this particular equation.

Comment: Maybe Wolfram transformed your equation into a polynomial contianing $\sin x, \cos x, \sin^2 x$ and further rewriting it into a quartic equation in $\sin x$, by the relation $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=1$?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not always try to simplify trigonometric expressions.

Comment: As @stevengregory notes, Wolfram Alpha doesn't always automatically simplify. (Note that there are numerous instances of $\cos^2b+\sin^2b$ and such in the result.) Applying the`Simplify[]` command should help. Whatever happens  though, one should expect a complicated result; the equation is effectively quartic in $\cos x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(New result added at the end)

In
$\sin(a-x) + 2\sin(b-2x) = 0
$,
let $y = a-x$
so
$x = a-y$.
This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=\sin(y)+2\sin(b-2(a-y))\\
&=\sin(y)+2\sin(b-2a+2y)\\
&=\sin(y)+2\sin(c+2y)
\qquad c = b-2a\\
&=\sin(y)+2(\sin(c)\cos(2y)+\cos(c)\sin(2y))\\
&=\sin(y)+2(\sin(c)(1-2\sin^2(y))+2\cos(c)\cos(y)\sin(y))\\
&=\sin(y)+2u(1-2\sin^2(y))+4v\cos(y)\sin(y))
\qquad u = \sin(c), v = \cos(c)\\
\end{array}
$

so

$4v\cos(y)\sin(y)
= -\sin(y)-2u(1-2\sin^2(y))
$
or,
if $s = \sin(y)$,
$4vs\sqrt{1-s^2}
= -s-2u(1-2s^2)
= -s-2u+4us^2
$.

If we square this,
the result is a quartic
$4v^2s^2(1-s^2)
=(-s-2u+4us^2)^2
$
or
$4(1-u^2)s^2(1-s^2)
=(-s-2u+4us^2)^2
$.

This is a quartic in $s$
which will probably
have a very messy solution
like the one you have.

(added later)

If $c = \pi/4$
so $u^2 = \frac12$,
the resulting equation
according to Wolfy is
$-10 s^4 + 4 \sqrt{2} s^3 + 9 s^2 - 2 \sqrt{2} s - 2 = 0
$
which, surprisingly,
has roots
$\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\approx \pm 0.70711$
and
$\dfrac15(\sqrt{2}\pm2\sqrt{3})
\approx -0.40998, 0.97566
$.